# state having different values on the different functions

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm using nextjs and I have custom select componet that opens the options when I click on it, but I want to be able to close it when I click anywhere on screen, but I don't understand why the state value is not working properly

```
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  console.log(isOpen);

  const handleClickOutside = () => {
    console.log(isOpen);

    if (isOpen) setIsOpen(false);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }, [selectedAgent]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
  }, []);
<ul>
   <li>
       <input type="radio" name="agent"
                value={name} 
                onChange={() =>
                  setSelectedAgent({
                    name,
                    extension,
                    path,
                  })
                }
              />
</li>
</ul>
```

the value on console log says it's true but when it's inside the function it says false I want to close the box when I click for example on the building picture
just to make it clear, the image building and the component are not in the same file, the image is inside the layout file like this
[image]

```
<div>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <div>
          <Image
            src={'/building.svg'}
            alt="building"
            width={614}
            height={467}
          />
        </div>
        {children}
      </main>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback to `useEffect` only runs once, when the component first loads, because of the empty dependency array.  *At that time* `isOpen` has its initial value of `false`.  Future re-renders don't re-create the click handler, so internal to that handler function the value never changes.

You can re-create the click handler whenever the value changes by adding it to the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
}, [isOpen]); // <--- here
```